# Validate the quantity of associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Given this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
  MAX_PHOTOS = 5
  validate :quantity_of_photos

  def quantity_of_photos
    ???
  end
end
```

And this:

```
@user.photos.size  # => 5
```

I need this to fail:

```
@user.photos << Photo.create(valid_photo_attributes)
```

How do I do this validation?

Answer (score 1):

Move the quantity of photos method to the Photo model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :user
   validates :quantity_of_photos

    def quantity_of_photos
      if new_record? && user.photos.size >= User::MAX_PHOTOS
        errors.add_to_base "You cannot have more than #{MAX_PHOTOS} photos."
      end
    end

end
```

The validity of a ActiveRecord instance is determined by whether there are errors in it's errors array.

Comment: Your method results in @user failing validation, but that's not quite it.  I need this <code>@user.photos << Photo.create(valid_photo_attributes)</code> to produce an error.  Otherwise, Photos can be associated successfully to Members until, at some point later in the code, a validation occurs. Better they can't be associated in the first place.

Comment: This would do it, but it's poor design.  It requires Photo to know what's going on with a Member and any other model that has photos and needs similar validation.